# I can't run pastebin script using curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I want to run this script using command line  in Termux

`curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/8eAPHAsY |bash`
but it adds /r after commands .
How can i fix it I am noob

Comment: `curl ... | tr -d '\r' | bash` -- as described in the linked duplicate, `\r` (not `/r`) is how a DOS carriage return is represented by a UNIX shell (or in C printf-style format strings in general).

Comment: (mind, with my security hat on, `curl | bash` is a bad idea in general, so consider a certain amount of eyebrow-raising to have happened; it's even possible for a web server to detect when a copy of `bash` is on the other side of a connection and provide malicious code only when there's a direct pipe, but not when a human is reading the script themselves).